# org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, osgi, deserialization, classloader

I am using org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils, but i got an error. i am a Java newbie if you need more information, please let me know
code:

```
Profile profile2 = new Profile();
profile2.setFileName(path);
profile2.setStatus("UPLOADED");
byte[] payload2 = SerializationUtils.serialize(profile2);
profile = (Profile) SerializationUtils.deserialize(payload2);
```

run time Error output:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxx.xxx.Profile
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:166)
        at org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:193)
```

people says Profile is not in classpath. if that was true, error would happen on "new Profile()". am I right?

I just found a workaround:

```
profile = (EveSuccessCriteriaProfile) SerializationUtils.deserialize(payload2);
```

replaced by

```
InputStream fis = null;
fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload2);
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
profile = (Profile) o.readObject();
```

it works fine

Comment: The jar containing Profile class is not in classpath hence JVM cannot find the class and this results in error

Comment: if profile class was not in classpath, compiler should complain. right? it should fail on "Profile profile2 = new Profile();" instead of "profile = (Profile) SerializationUtils.deserialize(payload2);"

Comment: This is the compiler complaining :) :) , In java every class will be loaded by a classloader now when classloader tries to load a class from the classpath and that is not found then it will complain about this.

Comment: it failed on run time. i guess something to do with classloader

Comment: Yep, agree with you, its on runtime while trying to carry out serialization

Comment: do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: are you using maven/gradle? if yes use CNTR + Shift + T to check from where your class is getting resolved - com.xxx.xxx.Profile. it should get resolved from only one jar and not from multiple jars.

Comment: find the jar containing Profile class and add it to your classpath in eclipse Project-> Right Click -> Java Build Path -> Library -> Add Jars or if you are not using any IDE then use the java -cp (path to your jar file) MainClassName, I guess you would be using -cp option in javac but not in the java command

Comment: @cppython The compiler has nothing to do with it. This is runtime. The compiler has been and gone.

Comment: @EJP . i knew there is nothing to do with compiler. but profile class is there. I am using spring and osgi. classloader may have problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that in OSGi there is not only once classloader that loaded all classes. There is one classloader per bundle. So if you do Profile.class.getClassLoader() you will get the classloader of the bundle that contains Profile. If you do SerializationUtils.class.getClassLoder() then you will get the classloader of the commons.lang bundle. As commons.lang does not have an Import-Package for your the package Profile is in it will not see it.
So if SerializationUtils.deserialize uses its own classloader to load the Profile class it will not find it.

I am pretty sure it will then try to use the ThreadContext classloader to load the user class. So it might help to do
    `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Profile.class.getClassLoader());` before the calls to SerializationUtils.deserialize.

This is only a workaround though. The deserialize call should be enhanced to accept a ClassLoader as a second argument. So dont get into the habbit to see the ContextClassLoader as a best practice.

Unfortunately SerializationUtils simply does not work in OSGi. You will have to wait for this issue to be resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1049

You should try with https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.html that should allow to do the deserialization cleanly without buddy classloading or similar.

Comment: I believe you are on the right direction but the fix doesnt work. i applied Thread .xxx right before SerialzationUtil.deserialize, the same error comes back again

Comment: Found the issue ... no luck in this case I fear